# How to maintain the visibility of Tooltip after closing a form in React JS

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, bootstrap-modal, antd

I am using Tooltip for showing validation message in my Form(which is a Modal).
[image]

I have a cancel button in the Form. When I click the cancel button (Cancel button isn't included in the below images) and redirected to the index page, the tooltip remains in the index page as shown:
[image]

The code used for tooltip in form.js

```
<div style={{ 'height': '46px', 'display': 'flex'}}>
  <label style={{ 'color': '#f5222d', 'paddingTop': '10px', 'fontFamily': 'SimSun'}}>*</label>&nbsp;
  <label style={{ 'width': '70px', 'paddingTop': '8px'}}>Customer Name:</label>
  <FormItem>
    {getFieldDecorator('Name', { initialValue: '', rules: [{ required: true, message: (
    <Tooltip visible={true} placement="topRight" title="Please Input Customer Name" /> ), }], })(
    <Input placeholder="Customer Name" style={{ 'width': '164px'}} onChange={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); this.handleChange(0,e, 'Name')}}/> )}
  </FormItem>
</div>
```

Code for Cancel button in index.js

```
handleModelCancel = () => {
  this.setState({  isModelOpen:false });
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

On handleModelCancel function you need to write a logic for tooltip that is you need to do visible false for Tooltip
Instead of passing boolean value direct to visible pass the variable whose value is boolean value for eg:

```
`<Tooltip visible={this.state.isTooltipVisible}>`
```

make the isTooltipVisible value false in handleModelCancel function.

Hope that helps you!